# R-exams: extol command in Meta information

Tags: r-exams

I just started working in R-exams package to prepare a set of dynamic questions. I am puzzled with the command "extol" in Meta information of the exercise:

```
Meta-information
================
extol: 0.01
```

For instance, in the example above, what exactly does "extol=0.01" mean? Is 0.01 a percent of the amount that is tolerable? And where could I possibly get detailed information on tolerance specification "extol" in r-exams package?

Is it actually possible to set the tolerance as the percentage of the amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extol` meta-information sets the absolute tolerance of the `exsolution`. Thus, `exsolution` plus/mins `extol` is the interval which is accepted as correct.

To set a relative tolerance you can use the `num_to_tol()` function which converts a numeric solution to an absolute tolerance. It also assures a certain minimal tolerance. See the source code for the precise computation:

```
num_to_tol
## function (x, reltol = 2e-04, min = 0.01, digits = 2) 
## pmax(min, round(reltol * abs(x), digits = digits))
```

This function is useful if the order of magnitude of the correct answer can change substantially across different random replications:

```
exams::num_to_tol(10)
## [1] 0.01
exams::num_to_tol(100)
## [1] 0.02
## exams::num_to_tol(1000)
## [1] 0.2
exams::num_to_tol(10000)
## [1] 2
```

The default of `reltol = 2e-04` and `min = 0.01` was chosen based on our needs and experiences in our own exams. You might prefer different specifications, of course.

To apply it in a given exercise for a solution in a variable `sol`, say, you typically do:

```
exsolution: `r sol`
extol: `r num_to_tol(sol)`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It seems to be working perfectly. I just specified ```extol: `r num_to_tol(Value, reltol=2e-02, min=0.01, digits=2)` ```